# Ruby looping over 2 hash arrays and comparing key values

Tags: ruby

I'm having a problem while I'm trying to loop over two hash arrays.
my hashes looks like:

```
h1= [
  {"name"=>"postgresql", "version"=>29},
  {"name"=>"java", "version"=>8},
  {"name"=>"python", "version"=>3}
]

h2= [
  {"name"=>"postgresql", "release"=>"postgresql-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/postgresql-release"},
  {"name"=>"java", "release"=>"java-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/java-release"}
]

combined = []
```

I need to combine these two hashes in an array called `combined` after I check for the hash value of "name" field in h1 and h2 , so that:

- if `h1["name"] == h2["name"]` ---> save the name, version, release and url.
- And if `h1["name"] != h2["name"]` (e.g: python is found in h1 but not in h2) ---> save the name, version, release = nil, url = nil

`combined` array should look like this:

```
combined = [
  {"name"=>"postgresql", "version"=>29, "release"=>"postgresql-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/postgresql-release"},
  {"name"=>"java", "version"=>8, "release"=>"java-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/java-release"},
  {"name"=> "python", "version"=>3, "release"=> nil, "url"=> nil}
]
```

I have tried a lot and was always having more iterations and/or can't print anything in case of different names.

My code looks something like:

```
h1= [{"name"=>"postgresql", "version"=>29}, {"name"=>"java", "version"=>8}, {"name"=>"python", "version"=>3}]

h2= [{"name"=>"postgresql", "release"=>"postgresql-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/postgresql-release"}, {"name"=>"java", "release"=>"java-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/java-release"}]

combined = []

h1.each do |h1Key, h1Value|
  h2.each do |h2Key, h2Value|
    if h1["name"] == h2["name"]
      combined << {"name"=> h1["name"], "version"=> h1["version"], "release"=> h2["release"], "url"=> h2["url"]} 
    else
      combined << {"name"=> h1["name"], "version"=> h1["version"], "release"=> nil, "url"=> nil}
    end
  end
end
puts combined.to_s
```

I also couldn't compare values of h1 and h2 properly.

Your help is so much appreciated as I'm still pretty new to Ruby and unfortunately my logic isn't helping me out.

Thanks in advance! ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, h1 and h2 are arrays of hashes, not hashes themselves. If you iterate over them, you get each hash in the array, not key and value of some hash.

For clarity, lets rename them to `a1` and `a2` instead.

```
a1= [{"name"=>"postgresql", "version"=>29}, {"name"=>"java", "version"=>8}, {"name"=>"python", "version"=>3}]
a2= [{"name"=>"postgresql", "release"=>"postgresql-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/postgresql-release"}, {"name"=>"java", "release"=>"java-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/java-release"}]

combined = []
```

Now when we iterate over them, we get each hash in turn.

```
a1.each do |h1|
```

For each hash in the first array, we want to find the corresponding hash in the 2nd array. If we're looking at java in the first array and find postgresql in the 2nd, that doesn't mean that there is no java. We just need to ignore it for now. If we don't find a match, then we'll assign nil-s

```
h2 = a2.find { |h| h1["name"] == h["name"] } || {}
```

Now that we have either found a match or not found a match, we can just add the result to the combined array as you did.

```
combined << {"name"=> h1["name"], "version"=> h1["version"], "release"=> h2["release"], "url"=> h2["url"]}
```

All together:

```
a1= [{"name"=>"postgresql", "version"=>29}, {"name"=>"java", "version"=>8}, {"name"=>"python", "version"=>3}]
a2= [{"name"=>"postgresql", "release"=>"postgresql-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/postgresql-release"}, {"name"=>"java", "release"=>"java-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/java-release"}]

combined = []

a1.each do |h1|
  h2 = a2.find { |h| h1["name"] == h["name"] } || {}
  combined << {"name"=> h1["name"], "version"=> h1["version"], "release"=> h2["release"], "url"=> h2["url"]} 
end
puts combined.to_s #=> [{"name"=>"postgresql", "version"=>29, "release"=>"postgresql-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/postgresql-release"}, {"name"=>"java", "version"=>8, "release"=>"java-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/java-release"}, {"name"=>"python", "version"=>3, "release"=>nil, "url"=>nil}]
```

A slightly simpler way would be to use `map`. Then you can avoid the additional array and manual appending

```
a1= [{"name"=>"postgresql", "version"=>29}, {"name"=>"java", "version"=>8}, {"name"=>"python", "version"=>3}]
a2= [{"name"=>"postgresql", "release"=>"postgresql-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/postgresql-release"}, {"name"=>"java", "release"=>"java-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/java-release"}]

combined = a1.map do |h1|
  h2 = a2.find { |h| h1["name"] == h["name"] } || {}
  {"name"=> h1["name"], "version"=> h1["version"], "release"=> h2["release"], "url"=> h2["url"]} 
end
puts combined.to_s #=> [{"name"=>"postgresql", "version"=>29, "release"=>"postgresql-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/postgresql-release"}, {"name"=>"java", "version"=>8, "release"=>"java-release", "url"=>"https://github.com/repo/java-release"}, {"name"=>"python", "version"=>3, "release"=>nil, "url"=>nil}]
```

Another possible improvement is to use merge.

```
combined = a1.map do |h1|
  h2 = a2.find { |h| h1["name"] == h["name"] } || { "release" => nil, "url" => nil}
  h1.merge(h2)
end
```

Comment: It works great! I've implemented the first variant as it's the easiest for me to understand at the moment, due to the lack of knowledge in Ruby! :)
I have a question regarding this part:

`h2 = a2.find { |h| h1["name"] == h["name"] } || {}`
I couldn't get what's happening exactly, could you please explain to me again step by step?
Thank you so much for your help ^^

Comment: Sure. `find` will start going over the array and running the block until it finds the first one where the block returns `true` (or anything truthy). Then returns that. If it finds nothing and reaches the end, it returns `nil`. So I'm iterating over the 2nd array looking for a hash with the same name. If I find it, good. If I don't, I default to empty hash (`|| {}`) because calling `h2["release"]` on an empty hash returns nil by default. This makes the following code simpler by having h2 always be a hash. Then I don't have to check if it's present or not later.

Comment: Great explanation!!! I get it right now and the mentioned doc helped even more. Many thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
combined = h1
  .concat(h2)
  .group_by { |a| a['name'] }
  .values
  .map do |a|
    res = a.first.merge(a.last)
    res['release'] ||= nil
    res['url'] ||= nil
    res
  end
```

If you're not sure of what is doing the code, try doing it step by step.

Comment: It works as expected thank you so much for trying to help!

Comment: My pleasure. Don't hesitate to validate my answer :)

Comment: Sure I've already done, but I still need 15 reputation points in order for others to see it. As soon as i get them my validation is going to be visible!

Comment: Oh, ok ^^ Thx :)

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a lot of ways to do this, but since your inner hashes essentially have a key, the first that comes to mind is to turn your arrays of hashes into hashes of hashes and then simply use Hash#deep_merge which does exactly this sort of thing.

```
hash1 = h1.index_by { |inner_hash| inner_hash['name'] }
hash2 = h2.index_by { |inner_hash| inner_hash['name'] }
combined_hash = hash1.deep_merge(hash2)
combined = combined_hash.values
```

This gives your expected output except for the python nil URL. If you can't fix that in the data, to replicate that result, try something like this:

```
# ... as before
defaults = {'url' => nil, 'version' => nil}
combined_hash = combined_hash.transform_values { |v| defaults.merge(v) }
combined = combined_hash.values
```

If you need the defaults to be the exact keys in the data which may change:

```
keys = (hash1.keys + hash2.keys).uniq
defaults = keys.map { |k| [k, nil] }.to_h
```

Comment: Instead of the first `map`-s, you could use `index_by`. Meant for exactly that:
`h1.index_by { |h| h['name'] }`